# How to delete a build in Concourse?

Tags: concourse

Is there any way to delete a build within Concourse? So far, I couldn't find anything about that in the fly or the main documentation. It looks like I can only destroy the whole pipeline which would be overkill.

Ideally, I'd like to just keep builds from the last, say, 10 days around and delete everything else unless I explicitly mark a build (similar to how Jenkins allows you to set a retention for builds).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure Concourse to only keep logs for the last N builds with [`build_logs_to_retain`](http://concourse.ci/single-page.html#build_logs_to_retain).

Comment: Awesome, thank you :) I completely missed this flag.